# Clang disable inlining getelementptr

Tags: clang, llvm, compiler-flags, inlining

I have the following simple c code.

```
int a[2] = {1,2};
int main(){
    return a[0];
}
```

Now the IR that clang generates for this case is as follows.

```
%retval = alloca i32, align 4
store i32 0, i32* %retval, align 4
%0 = load i32, i32* getelementptr inbounds ([2 x i32], [2 x i32]* @a, i64 0, i64 0), align 4
ret i32 %0
```

As seen, the getelementptr instruction is inlined inside of the load instruction. Is there a way to disable this inlining in clang? I'm using clang version 3.8.0.

Comment: Why do you want to disable this? It's just that the `getelementptr` is a constant expression instead of an instruction.

Comment: I causes some difficulties in our analysis code if we have to discover the getelementptr instruction as a part of the load instruction instead of discovering it separate before. We could handle this case by using a check for the getelementptr expression, but that just adds some complexity to the code that I am looking to do without

Comment: As far as I know there's no builtin clang / llvm option to do this. If you're 100% sure you need this, you might look at this [`BreakConstantGEPs`](https://github.com/spurious/safecode-mirror/blob/master/lib/ArrayBoundChecks/BreakConstantGEPs.cpp) pass as a starting point. I have no idea if it works with latest llvm though (the last commit message mentions 3.3).

Comment: thanks..will take a look